# Runtime Error 438 Hiding Page

Tags: ms-access, vba

I receive a

> run-time error 438

when changing visibility of a page in Access VBA. The code below is called "AfterUpdate" for a listbox. I believe my syntax is correct after much review. I've tested the conditional statements with MsgBox's successfully.

Any ideas?

```
Public Sub RefreshControlTabs()
If [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData]![Channel].Value = "Mail" Then
    [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData].[tabChannelControl].Pages(0).Visible = True
    [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData].[tabChannelControl].Pages(1).Visible = False

ElseIf [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData]![Channel].Value.Value = "Email" Then
    [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData].[tabChannelControl].Pages(1).Visible = True
    [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData].[tabChannelControl].Pages(0).Visible = False

Else
    'do nothing
    MsgBox "Valid Email/Mail channel not found for this job."
    [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData].[tabChannelControl].Pages(0).Visible = True
    [Forms]![frmPrintPostage_Email_DB]![subfrm_CampaignData].[tabChannelControl].Pages(1).Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it fail on? Why are these forms fully qualified like this? Does this code live on another form?

Comment: It fails on line 3 (or any of the page visibility changes). This code lives in a module that is called from a Listbox event (AfterUpdate).
also, the listbox and the tabs live in the same unbound form

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your line:

```
ElseIf [Forms]! ... [Channel].Value.Value = "Email" Then
```

Should be:

```
ElseIf [Forms]! ... [Channel].Value = "Email" Then
```

Comment: I don't know why people add the .Value as it's the default property. 
It's unnecessary in access.

Comment: Some cats like to be old school @Minty

Comment: Ah thanks - an obvious error there haha. The runtime error occurs on line 3